# PHPStorm - перенос проектов

Tags: phpstorm, проекты

Скопировал файлы проектов на другой компьютер.

Экспортировал/Импортировал настройки *PHPStorm*. Все успешно.

Открываю проект - нет связи с удаленным сервером (*ftp*).

Фактически нужны функции *Deployment* - сейчас они недоступны.

Сами сервера в системе «прописались»: если создавать новый проект, то можно их использовать - все работает.

Как связать проект и удаленный сервер, что бы все не перезаливать?

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть такая проблема. 
Нужно открыть **File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment**

Выбрать Ваше *ftp* соединение и на вкладке **Mapping** указать по новой **Deployment path on server**

После этого все снова станет активным